# Accordion layout not filling available height using CSS calc() when varying the font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css

The situation that I'm facing is with an accordion control that I'm building. As defined there are four sections within this example. The goal is to allow the "open" section to fully fill the available vertical space. To achieve this effect I'm using the following `height:` calculation (determined by trial and error - let's call this a magic number / hack):

```
height:calc(100vh - 11.9em);
```

The result is acceptable for the given `font-size:`, but when I increase the `font-size:` a gap at the bottom appears - and when I decrease the `font-size:` the accordion exceeds the available vertical space...

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Neoheurist/hq7xmfv4/) that I built to figure this out.

I really want to get this example working, but more importantly I want to understand the in's and out's of layout calculation (is there a good web resource / tutorial about this)?

Comment: After further experimentation it has become clear to me that using `px` (pixel units) is problematic for page resizing/scaling - within the JSFIDDLE I converted everything to `em` (the size of the current font) and I now have a working example that behaves well at all scales.... because as the page is resized the `font-size` is automatically resizing also

Comment: I am still concerned that I don't understand why the magic value within the calculation of the `height` - what element sizes are comprising this value?

`height:calc(100vh - 11.9em);`

Comment: And I still haven't been able to find a good resource that teaches how to logically determine scaling factors/values such as this on...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that every 10% difference equates to 1.7em (inverse) difference in your calculated height. 1.7em is the handle font-size plus its padding.

Not sure of the math though.